# WPF DataGrid Get Cell Value Using Button

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Data Grid. When I click the delete button, I want to get the ID column value in my data grid. How can I do that?

This is my data grid xaml.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgridUser" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Click="btnDelete_Click" >Delete</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, by adding this code to my button. Basically, when I clicked the button. It will get the row where button is clicked and then get the select the value from specific column.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = YOURDATAGRIDNAME;
    DataGridRow Row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dataGrid.SelectedIndex);
    DataGridCell RowAndColumn = (DataGridCell)dataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(Row).Parent;
    string CellValue = ((TextBlock)RowAndColumn.Content).Text;

    MessageBox.Show(CellValue);
}
```